# How to escape ' for a:contains(...)

Tags: jquery

How can I escape content for characters such as an apostrophe ?

The following a:contains is choking on the string literal

```
$('a:contains('\This'is choking on the apostrophe\')....
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('a:contains("This isn\'t choking on the apostrophe")')
```

Or this:

```
$("a:contains('This isn\'t choking on the apostrophe')")
```

Comment: How about `$('a:contains(\'This isn\'t choking on the apostrophe\')');` ?

Comment: @RustyTheBoyRobot: thx but I should have been more clear....how can I do this programatically?  say the string is being passed in as a param.  and I want to do this for all characters being passed in...

Comment: @VisioN: you beat me to it! Yep, perfecto! Thank you!